# my edit button can not change to done, delete row by swiping

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am working on UITableView and I am doing a deletion. As far as I know there are 2 ways to delete a row

> 1. swiping from the left to right and Delete button will appears so that you can do a deletion
> 2. add EDIT button to right top right or left. By clicking on it, EDIT will change to DONE and each row of a table will have a red circle
>      with (-) sign in front of each. Click on it , delete button will
>      appear and you can process

I noticed that if you do have an EDIT button and use the method 1 to delete, the EDIT button also change to DONE...However, after swiping it, mine is still EDIT. does any one encounter this problem before, please help. All comments are welcomed here. Thanks

Comment: This is expected behaviour. It's how an editable view controller was designed by Apple. When one cell is in delete mode, the edit button is unaffected, however, when in edit mode, the edit button shows "Done". It's unadvisable to change this behaviour, since it's what users will be used to.

Answer (score 2):

Swipe to delete happens when the view is not in edit mode. It's supposed to be a quick way to delete items when browsing the view. Check out how it works in the Mail app for example - you can either tap to edit all rows, or just swipe to delete one of them.

So basically it's working correctly.

However, if you want to override the standard behaviour, you can call setEditing: on the viewController to toggle the mode programmatically, which will also update the edit button.

Comment: yeah I know but my problem is when I swipe, the EDIT can not be change to DONE...

Comment: That may just be an extra feature Apple added to Mail that isn't in the standard controller behaviour. Like I said, I don't think it's a bug or a problem, but if you want you can toggle the done button using setEditing.

Comment: If the problem is that when you swipe to delete the row doesn't actually get deleted, that's because you need to implement the tableView:commitEditingStyle: delegate method to actually delete the row from the table.

Answer (score 1):

Add the Edit button using the ViewdidLoad method

```
-(void)viewDidLoad;
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self editButtonItem];
}
```

And for the delete method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPath:[NSArray arrayWithObject: indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: i can delete the row but still can not change EDIT to DONE after swiping from left to right....

Comment: can you post the code on how you added the edit/done button? If you use [self editButtonItem], then it should toggle by itself..

Comment: What i did is    // Add Edit button to the right and handle click event 
 UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" 
                                                                 style :UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                                                                 target:self    
                                                                 action:@selector(EditMode:)];
 [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:addButton];*

Comment: replace all that code with just `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [self editButtonItem];`

Comment: if you do that so you can not click on the EDIT button to do the deletion. J have just tried it. My goal is to archive both ways for deletion.

Comment: try adding `[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPath:[NSArray arrayWithObject: indexPath] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationFade];` in your _commitEditingStyle_

Answer (score 0):

To get this behavior you need to implement these two delegate methods:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.editing = YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.editing = NO;
}
```